# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined error while on Parcel React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component code for my previous JS code called home.js, which is supposed to show the home page of my website.

```js
import React from 'react';
//import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Home(props) {
    return <main>
        <header>
        <h1>The [RETACTED] Club</h1>
        <h2>&#x1f914; Why [RETACTED]?</h2>
        <p>Here we explain why the [RETACTED] club exists</p>
        <h2>&#x2757 Risks of [RETACTED]</h2>
        <p>The fun, challenges, and risks of the club will be explained here.</p>
        <h2>&#x1f397 Why [RETACTED]?</h2>
        <p>Here we explain the pros and cons of our launch site.</p>
        </header>
            <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2021, [RETACTED], SAGTRHYDTJHSYHSRTGAERFefef
        <a href="mailto:[RETACTED]@gmail.com">[RETACTED]@gmail.com</a></p>
    </footer>
    </main>

}

export default Home;
//  ReactDOM.render(contents,
//document.getElementById('root')
//);
```

This is the JS code I used to show that HTML.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Home from "./home";

let contents = <Home />;  

ReactDOM.render(contents, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I was supposed to type parcel index.html in the command prompt to make the home page work, but every time I try to save my file, I get this error.

```
Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at Bundler.createBundleTree (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:654:54)
    at Bundler.createBundleTree (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:721:12)
    at Bundler.createBundleTree (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:721:12)
    at Bundler.bundle (C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-7TNLM47\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:298:14)
```

I want to know how this error appeared and how I can fix it.

Comment: There is an [github](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2749) issue on this, you may check the progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add the CLI command `--log-level verbose` for order to know which problem you have. And perhaps you have to use the CLI `--no-scope-hoist`. You can find more info: [docs parcel about scope-hoisting](https://parceljs.org/features/scope-hoisting/)